# Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating $.body.append)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, webview

I am trying to use javascript to set the append html of a body, but for some reason, it isn't working. I have found that others have had this problem before, but none of the solutions I found in other posts works. I don't understand what's wrong.

Here is my test function:

```js
function(data) {
     item = {"name": "xxxx", age: 40}
     $.body.append("<a href="#!">" +item["name"]+ "</a>")
}
```

I got this Error in python webview:

```
xxx.html:42TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.body.append')
```

Everything I have found online says that this should work. I am lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably meant `$('body').append`. The jQuery object does not have a `body` property

Comment: Yes @Phil i tried this also. but still same error.

Comment: You have incorrect quote nesting as well. Try `$(document.body).append('<a href="#!">' + item.name + '</a>')`

Comment: I've never seen this syntax. `$("body").append(***)` instead?

Comment: thanks @ Phil $(document.body).append('<a href="#!">' + item.name + '</a>') this one is working.

Comment: No @xufox, I mean I've never seen `$.body` struck me as wack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(data) {
 item = {"name": "xxxx", age: 40}
 $.body.append("<a href="#!">" +item["name"]+ "</a>")
}
```

As suggested above that **$.body** is not a jQuery syntax.

However, you can do this with javascript like **document.body**.

After all, both doesn't work correctly until you append your string correctly.

you have to do something like :

```
$(document.body).append("<a href='#!'>"+item.name+"</a>");
```

And the last correct please do not forget to define your variable item inside function(data) if you haven't defined it globally.

So your function would be:

```
function(data) {
     var item = {"name": "xxxx", age: 40};
    $(document.body).append("<a href='#!'>"+item.name+"</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems.

1) `$.body` is not the correct syntax to access body.

`$('body')` is correct.

2) Your string formation is not correct. You have to wrap with `''` when you use `""` inside that string or viceversa.

Should be

```
  $('body').append('<a href="#!">' +item["name"]+ '</a>');
```